# Cannot install PySpotify module for python due to gcc failed

Tags: python, command, spotify, libspotify

I have been trying to install the pySpotify module. I already installed libspotify and added the libspotify.dll folder to the path. When I try installing pyspotify as a next step I am getting the following error messages. Any ideas?

I am using python 2.7.5 on Windows 7

```
C:\Users\paulmiles\Documents\GitHub\pyspotify>python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'spotify._spotify' extension
c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -Isrc -IC:\PYTHON27\include -IC:
\PYTHON27\PC -c src/module.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\module.o
src/module.c:3:28: error: libspotify/api.h: No such file or directory
In file included from src/module.c:4:
src/pyspotify.h:47: error: expected ')' before 'error'
src/pyspotify.h:48: error: expected ')' before 'error'
In file included from src/module.c:5:
src/artist.h:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_artist'
src/artist.h:11: error: expected ')' before '*' token
In file included from src/module.c:6:
src/artistbrowser.h:5: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_artis
tbrowse'
src/artistbrowser.h:13: error: expected ')' before '*' token
In file included from src/module.c:7:
src/album.h:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_album'
src/album.h:11: error: expected ')' before '*' token
In file included from src/module.c:8:
src/albumbrowser.h:5: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_albumb
rowse'
src/albumbrowser.h:13: error: expected ')' before '*' token
In file included from src/module.c:9:
src/link.h:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_link'
In file included from src/module.c:10:
src/playlist.h:6: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_playlist'
src/playlist.h:15: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_playlist_
callbacks'
src/playlist.h:22: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_playlist'

src/playlist.h:28: error: expected ')' before '*' token
In file included from src/module.c:11:
src/playlistcontainer.h:6: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_p
laylistcontainer'
src/playlistcontainer.h:11: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_
playlistcontainer_callbacks'
src/playlistcontainer.h:18: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_
playlistcontainer'
src/playlistcontainer.h:29: error: expected ')' before '*' token
In file included from src/module.c:12:
src/playlistfolder.h:7: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_uint
64'
src/playlistfolder.h:18: error: expected ')' before '*' token
In file included from src/module.c:13:
src/search.h:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_search'
src/search.h:11: error: expected ')' before '*' token
In file included from src/module.c:14:
src/session.h:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_session'
src/session.h:8: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before
'*' token
src/session.h:12: error: expected ')' before 'error'
src/session.h:15: error: expected ')' before '*' token
In file included from src/module.c:15:
src/toplistbrowser.h:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_topl
istbrowse'
src/toplistbrowser.h:11: error: expected ')' before '*' token
In file included from src/module.c:16:
src/track.h:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_track'
src/track.h:11: error: expected ')' before '*' token
In file included from src/module.c:17:
src/image.h:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_image'
src/image.h:11: error: expected ')' before '*' token
In file included from src/module.c:18:
src/user.h:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sp_user'
src/user.h:11: error: expected ')' before '*' token
src/module.c: In function 'init_spotify':
src/module.c:63: error: 'SPOTIFY_API_VERSION' undeclared (first use in this func
tion)
src/module.c:63: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
src/module.c:63: error: for each function it appears in.)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
src/module.c:3:28: error: libspotify/api.h: No such file or directory
```

is the source of your problems. Just having the DLL is not enough, the header needs to be available as well.

https://github.com/mopidy/pyspotify/issues/63 covers a similar issue and might provide some hints on how to fix this for Windows.